# Настройка Google Play Services в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-services

Не могли бы вы описать, что нужно сделать по пунктам, чтобы подключить Google Play Services к своему приложению, а также сделать простой рейтинг участников.

Суть приложения проста, Викторина: ответил правильно, тебе идет 1 очко в "правильно ответил(а)", ответил неправильно - 1 очко идет в "неправильно ответил(а)", и естественно рейтинг по сумме "Правильные ответы" - "Неправильные ответы" = у кого больше число, тот и на первом месте.

Пробовал подключить саму либу, а вот как сделать рейтинг, примеров не нашел в инете, на Хабре есть статья про рейтинг на Unity, а на Android Studio примеров не нашел, может кинете ссылку где почитать с примерами?

Answer (score -1):

Перевел с  гугла с помощью `google translate` и тебе советую если с английским плохо ,Вот что советует сам гуглик :

```
Set Up Play сервисы Google

Для того, чтобы разработать приложение с использованием API - интерфейсов сервисов Google Play Google , вам нужно настроить свой проект с помощью SDK сервисов Google Play. Если вы еще не установили SDK сервисов Google Play Google все же, чтобы получить это сейчас:

Запустите Android Studio .
На Сервис меню, нажмите Android SDK> Диспетчер .
Обновление Android Studio SDK менеджер : нажмите SDK Tools , разверните поддержки Repository , выберите Google Repository , а затем нажмите кнопку ОК .
```

> Добавить сервисы Google Play в проект

```
   1 Откройте build.gradleфайл в директории модуля приложения.

   2 Добавить новое правило сборки под dependenciesпоследнюю версию play-services. Например:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    ...

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    }

3.Сохраните изменения и нажмите Синхронизировать проект с Gradle файлов на панели инструментов.
```

Comment: я подключил либу, я не знаю как собственно сделать рейтинг и примеров не нахожу